# Failed to run a gradle task

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I try to run a gradle clean in cmd, but I have the message below:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':modules:project:project-api'.
```

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.getLifecycleTask()Lorg/gradle/api/Task;

Please note that this happens when I execute gradle via cmd. In eclipse everything is fine.

You think something could be wrong with its installation ?